# Custom Alphabetical Order for Index (Turkish)

Tags: sorting, makeindex, alphabet

I need your help for building a proper index for a book in Turkish language. I am using `\usepackage{makeidx}` to build my index, which produces the following image as a sample.

[image]

Here as you may see, the letters are sorted in the alphabetical order in English however, I want to redefine the ordering of the letters as follows:

- ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTYUÜVWXYZ
- abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyz

Comment: I guess that your main document use utf8, eiter with the corresponding option passed to inputenc with pdflatex or native utf8 with xelatex or lualatex. In this case you need an utf8 aware sorting program and hence not use makeindex. I recomand the use of utility  `upmendex` which is very efficient. I can't certify that the ordering will match exactly your aim but at least the word starting with ç or Ç will be on the same place as those with bare c ou C.

Comment: Besides, you also could use the @ optiom in index comand: `\index{Capraz@Çapraz}` will intruct makeindex that Çapraz must be sorted as if it would be Capraz.

Comment: @Jhor But wouldn't that sort Cauchy çarpımı > Çaprazoran > Chebyshev denklemi > Çözüm when the correct sorting order would be Cauchy çarpımı > Chebyshev denklemi > Çaprazoran > Çözüm, i.e throw "Ç" right in the middle there? This could be potentially much worse if there were more than four entries for C/Ç.

Comment: Maybey this thread can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98944/sorting-swedish-index-with-makeidx-correctly Somebody had a smilar problem with Swedish.

Comment: For `upmendex`, look at the manual page on http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/upmendex/man/upmendex.man1.pdf. You can add `icu_locale "tr"` in your `.ist` file, or fine tune ordering by settings  icu_rules on the same style file.